# Button with dropdown list as one option

Tags: buttons, dropdown

I need to give users a choice between two options, but one of them need to be specified by additional parameter before clicking. I'm struggling with showing the linkage between dropdown list of parameters and the button. In my first attempt, dropdown was just above the button, but I think "merging" them together is better.

Do you have any other ideas how to do this? Thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 3):

Have option 1 and option 2 inside a dropdown so that the user selects one of them. If they select option 2 from the dropdown then add the dynamic fields to add more info.

EDIT:
In case the additional data you require are mandatory and have a close connection, is a variant of the first option then you can add them in the same dropdown.

So the dropdown will now have

1. Spanish
2. English US
3. English UK

If they are not closely related and it demands a different input type then on selection of the dropdown have the input control below or on the side, depending on the form layout.

Comment: Thanks. So, if user wants to have option 1, he/she must first pick it from the dropdown list and submit with a button? Of course we can make the option 1 as default, but still - I don't feel it. What about dynamic fields - where should they appear?

I would rather let him do it via single click. In your solution everything seems hidden.

Comment: @mintpandapl can you please give an example for option 2 that requires extra data?And how does this fit in ?Is it a part of a form?More context would be helpful

Comment: I have replaced the image, it is still an example but might shed you some light

Comment: Have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since you have just 2 options, split the button in two halves with each containing a flag of the relevant type.

This way you take up the same amount of space as a single button while still providing two options. The split also makes it clear that the user has to choose (you can make one of the buttons being pressed cause the other to depress).

In this example I was hovering over the right option:[image]